# Webmin - Disallow access by IP

Tags: security, domain, ip-address

I have installed a Webmin instance. I can access by both `domain:port` and `ip:port`. Is there any way to **restrict** access to an **specific domain** name and **disallow** direct **access by IP**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webmin's integrated *miniserv* doesn't AFAIK have a feature like this. It seems to be a job for a proper reverse proxy with name-based virtual host support. This isn't hard to configure and is well described in Webmin documentation.

A good choice for a proxy is ie. *Apache httpd*.